# Perf crashing my RH

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, server-crashes

We are running perf on a 2.6.32-358.56.1.el6.x86_64 on an 8-core, dual socket machine. We have CPU iso on CPUs 1-31 (all except for 0), and our application is using CPUs 1-31. A few seconds into running perf with --pid set the entire blade crashes and we have to reset it manually. We don't see any logs in /var/log/messages. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: 1) What is displayed on the console? 2) What did Red Hat support say?

Comment: More details. This just isn't enough information.

Comment: is kdump enabled?